# Verificação de um elemento em uma lista de tuplas usando o comando in, observado somente um parametro em python

Tags: python, lista

Como verificar se uma tupla esta contida em uma lista usando a propriedade `in`. Exemplo:

```
lista = [('joao', 13), ('maria', 20), ('carlos', 30)]
```

Quero saber se `carlos` está contido na lista

Comment: A pergunta está um pouco contraditória. Primeiro você pede para verificar uma "tupla na lista", depois exemplifica uma "string na lista". Qual delas seria?

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito simples com `in` seria:

```
lista = [('joao', 13), ('maria', 20), ('carlos', 30)]

"carlos" in [x[0] for x in lista]
True
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**:

Conforme o comentário do Anderson, ficaria melhor da seguinte forma:

```
lista = [('joao', 13), ('maria', 20), ('carlos', 30)]

"carlos" in (x[0] for x in lista)
True
```

Você pode ver a diferença assim:

```
(x[0] for x in lista)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7ff4fc1af840>

[x[0] for x in lista]
['joao', 'maria', 'carlos']
```

Comment: Nota: ao utilizar *list comprehension* você acabará sempre tendo uma lista com todos os nomes em memória. Se a lista for muito grande isso pode ser um problema na aplicação. Se substituir por parenteses você terá um gerador e já contornará esse problema.

Answer (score 1):

Para utilizar o operador `in` nessa busca, você pode utilizar uma `list comprehension` para transformar sua lista com nomes e inteiros inicial em uma lista apenas com os nomes, conforme o Ricardo mencionou, o que pode ser considerado mais idiomático da linguagem Python:

```
names_and_ints = [('joao', 13), ('maria', 20), ('carlos', 30)]
only_names = [tpl[0] for tpl in names_and_ints]

"carlos" in only_names
>>> True
```

Ou você pode utilizar um for tradicional, o que também é de fácil compreensão:

```
names_and_ints = [('joao', 13), ('maria', 20), ('carlos', 30)]
only_names = []
for name, _ in names_and_ints:
   only_names.append(name)

"carlos" in only_names
>>> True
```

Lembrando que ambos os métodos salvam a lista em memória, fato que pode ser problemático se tal lista for muito grande.

Comment: O problema da lista pode ser resolvido com geradores, como [comentei aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/394802/verifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-um-elemento-em-uma-lista-de-tuplas-usando-o-comando-in-observado#comment776462_394807).

Comment: Perfeito, @AndersonCarlosWoss. É isso mesmo. Obrigado pelo complemento.